# download music file to local machine from external server

Tags: php, download

php code to download music file to local machine  from external server.
My music files are saved in an external server , and my site is in diverent server . How to code to download music file when user clicks on a download link in my main site. I need help please help me .

Thanks for your advice , but i have fixed this problem of mine  using the following code =>

```
    header ("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
            header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=soumik10.mp3;");
            header("Content-Length: ".$sz);
            readfile(SONGMAINURL.$server_file);
            exit;
```

Here $sz is the size of my musicfile located in  the external server , which i have found using this code =>

```
    ftp_size($conn_id, $source_server_file);
```

Comment: Use `curl` or `file_get_contents` to pull the file from the external server, and then send it to the user as an download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` to download the files from an external server.

Try the following code :

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
$err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);
if ($contents) return $contents;
else return FALSE;
}
```

Here, you have to pass the URL as a parameter to the above function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is file_get_contents() function to get the external file content:

```
// Set headers
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```